# Safari mobile and desktop are hiding full referrer URL: why?

Tags: http, url, safari, mobile-safari, http-referer

I have a website, `www.a.com`

In that website, I serve a page at `https://www.a.com/mypage` that contains this:

```
<script src='https://www.b.com/anotherpage'></script>
```

If I visit from every browser, `b.com` will receive this as http referrer:

`https://www.a.com/mypage`

However, if I visit from Safari mobile or desktop, the referrer becomes:

`https://www.a.com/`

Why? How can I force Safari to send the full referrer?

Example:

from Safari, b.com logs:

```
123.45.678.901 - - [06/Jun/2020:00:32:03 +0200] "GET /anotherpage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://www.a.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

from another browser:

```
123.45.678.901 - - [06/Jun/2020:00:31:34 +0200] "GET /anotherpage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://www.a.com/mypage/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
```

I've tried adding this:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="unsafe-url">
```

or this

```
<meta name="referrer" content="always">
```

to the `<head>` of `https://www.a.com/mypage` but to no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The incorrect behaviour in Safari (referrer being set to the domain only, without the URI), pertains to the fact that `Prevent cross-site tracking` is enabled.
Setting:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
<meta http-equiv='Referrer-Policy' content='no-referrer-when-downgrade'>
```

or setting `referrerPolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"` on the element (iframe, script tag, etc)

does not affect it.

See https://www.arcolatheatre.com/disable-prevent-cross-site-tracking/

Hope this helps someone,

Comment: Sorry the bounty already expired, because this is the only correct answer. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this is briliant. Saves me tons of time debugging.

Answer (score 6):

The value that is sent as the `Referer` header is determined by the Referrer Policy in effect for a given request. The chosen policy can come from a browser default, a HTTP header, a `meta` tag, or an attribute on the individual tag.

The difference you're seeing is probably because browsers [are moving](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#Directives) from a default of `no-referrer-when-downgrade` (which would show the full path in your case) to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` (which wouldn't, since it's a cross-origin request). Safari has presumably made that change while the others you tested haven't. (But note that [Chrome will be adopting the new default](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6251880185331712) in version 85).

Your attempt to use the `meta` tag should work, so if it doesn't, something might be interfering. You could try using one of the other mechanisms, like a `Referrer-Policy` header or a `<meta http-equiv='Referrer-Policy' content='no-referrer-when-downgrade'>` tag. Unfortunately, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility) Safari doesn't support the `referrerpolicy` attribute on the script tag.

Answer (score -2):

**You can't display the complete URL from your website confirguration/header. Now it is a configuration of your web browser.**

This is not a newest behavior, since 2014 apple is preventing to display url addresses can be bloated with incomprehensible text

You can take this references: [Next Safari for Mac hides full Web addresses](https://www.cnet.com/news/safari-for-mac-to-hide-full-web-site-addresses-too/)

Now, that is the "normal" behavior for `Safari` for `iOS` devices and Macs, but that doesn't means you can't disable it. If you want it, you can show full url's, you can go to `Safari` > `Preferences` > `Advacned` > Select `Show full website address`.

You can take this as a reference:

[How to Show the Full Website URL in Safari for Mac OS](https://osxdaily.com/2014/10/20/show-full-website-url-address-safari-mac-os-x/)

[How to Stop Safari From Hiding URL's](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250439746)

[How to See the Entire URL in Safari's Address Bar](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/safari-view-full-url)

Comment: My question is not about the URL you see in the address bar but the one sent in the HTTP Referrer header (unless the 2 things are linked?)

Comment: @Saturnix yes, are linked. Is not possible display full urls without modify the preferences in your system

Comment: @Saturnix I updated the answer. Sorry, it is not possible, now the url format is part of the web browser not the html page