# Not getting full path using req.get('Referrer') if in https

Tags: node.js, express

I have build a simple stats script  with express that uses an 1 pixel image to count visitors from a webpage. So we have 2 express scripts, one with the counter and one from the website being counted (so let’s call it the counter..and the website)

the counter has a the following route to generate the pixel:

```
 app.get("/p",(req, res) => {
  // code in the website  HTML template <img src="http://localhost:3001/p" height="1" width="1">
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'image/gif',
        'Content-Length': counterImg.length
      })

  let siteID = req.query.s;

  var ref = req.get('Referrer')

  console.log (“Ref is" + ref)
```

The objective is to obtain the full path (so not just the host but also the page name).

This works fine when tested locally ( hosting  both the counter and website  on http://localhost but with different ports)

and also works fine if the site to be tracked is hosted locally but in a live environment so between 2 servers both using https:// it just returns the referral domain without the path  e.g. site.com/ and not site.com/page1 etc.

Is this a normal behaviour for `req.get('Referrer')` or is it because of the nginx settings/https not sending over anything else but the host ?

LOCAL TO LOCAL

Ref is  http://localhost:3001/readme-page

LOCAL to COUNTER remotely in HTTPS

Ref is  http://localhost:3001/

Same for https to https … only the host appears

Ref is https://website.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is new, but is now the expected behavior.  I assume localhost gets special treatment, which is why it works locally.

[As of Chrome 85 (Aug 2020), the default referrer policy is `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default), which means that the `Referer` (sic) header will only contain the referring site's Origin (ie, no path) when cross-domain requests are made.

If you want the full path of your page sent to other origins, the referring page must have been sent with a [`Referrer-Policy` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) or include [`referrerpolicy` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-referrerpolicy) in HTML.

In other words, your tracking pixel should look like this:

```
<img src="https://example.com/p" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" height="1" width="1">
```

Comment: excellent thank you ! it was turning me mad :)  works fine on Chome but NOTE: this doesn't work on Safari unless the user changes the privacy settings as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62225068/safari-mobile-and-desktop-are-hiding-full-referrer-url-why